# Jointly training models in Tensorflow and Pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I have two models, model A in Tensorflow 2.0 and model B in Pytorch 1.3. Model A's output is B's input. I'd like to train the two models end-to-end.

Is it possible to do without porting one of the models to the other framework?

Comment: I don't have any solution, but if you're on GPU, you should probably load the Pytorch model first because tensorflow tends to take all the availqble memory in the GPU, which would leave nothing to Pytorch

Comment: Other than that, my biased opinion is that even if what you ask is possible, you'd lose less time if you translated any of the two models in the other framework so that you have two networks running in tensorflow or two in Pytorch.

Comment: The training has to be done with one framework or the other, so you must convert one of the two models. Maybe an independent format like ONNX can help (https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/PytorchTensorflowMnist.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is impossible to jointly train models in Tensorflow and Pytorch. Those two frameworks use very different backend architectures to calculate the loss and do backpropagation, so they are incompatible with each other for training deep learning models.

A more detailed question ought to be which Tensorflow model and which Pytorch are you using in your problem. With the development of the deep learning community, more and more basic deep learning algorithms have various versions of implementations and support both Pytorch and Tensorflow. It seldom happens that you can only find a unique implementation in either Pytorch and Tensorflow. Just try to find corresponding implementation and join them together!